# Can't access an object's attribute within an event

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a code like this:

```
var Obj = {
  el : document.getElementById("elementId"),

  doSomething : function(){ this.el.property = "value" }
};

Obj.el.addEventListener('click', Obj.doSomething);
```

but the element `this.el`  is undefined when the click event is fired ?
What causes this to happen?

NOTE: I don't know how to break the lines in the code in this editor, that's why it's in a single line.

Comment: It's hard to elaborate on why exactly it doesn't work, because there are a whole lot of different things that are quite wrong.  What made you think that something like this would work?

Comment: *"I don't know how to break the lines in the code in this editor"* When you were writing your question, to the right there was a box titled **How to Format**. Worth a read, as is the various information available from the **[?]** link above the question text area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript (unlike most other languages with similar syntax), `this` is defined entirely by *how* a function is called, not where it's defined. The way event handlers are called, `this` within your function doesn't refer to your object.

You can correct it in three ways:

1. If you're targeting [ES5](http://es5.github.com/)-enabled browsers or including an ES5 "shim", use [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5):

   ```
   var Obj = {
     el : document.getElementById,

     doSomething : function(){ this.el.property = "value" }
   };

   Obj.el.addEventListener('click', Obj.doSomething.bind(Obj));
   ```
2. Otherwise, use a [closure](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html):

   ```
   var Obj = {
     el : document.getElementById,

     doSomething : function(){ this.el.property = "value" }
   };

   Obj.el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       return Obj.doSomething(event);
   });
   ```
3. As RobG pointed out in the comments, because you have only **one** `Obj` object (rather than having a constructor function or something that will create more than one as necessary), you could just refer to that object using its variable (`Obj`) rather than `this`:

   ```
   var Obj = {
     el : document.getElementById,

     // Obj instead of this ---v
     doSomething : function(){ Obj.el.property = "value" }
   };

   Obj.el.addEventListener('click', Obj.doSomething);
   ```

   That only works when the object is a one-off within the scope in which it's defined (which is true for your `Obj` example). If the only reference you have to it were `this` (e.g., you didn't have `Obj`), you couldn't do this and would want one of the prior two options.

More:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

Note that your `el` property is suspect, though. You've defined it as

```
el : document.getElementById,
```

...which means that `el` now points to the *function* `getElementById`. That's probably not what you meant to do. Presumably you meant `el` to refer to a DOM element that you retrieved *via* `getElementById`, e.g.:

```
el : document.getElementById("someIdValue"),
```

More [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId).

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer and links to useful references, everything works now :)

Comment: well in my code, it is exactly as you mentioned, I didn't want to copy over all the code here, it looked messy in the first go, then I thought I would write something similar with only the code that don't work, I just missed the bit you mentioned by mistake

Comment: The OP could also use `Obj.el.property = value;`.

Comment: @RobG: Good point, in this specific case because there's just one object, that would work.

Comment: @fenerlitk: I've added a third option to the answer, per RobG's point.